# Does Zorn's lemma not hold for $\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Quote Wikipedia:

> Suppose a partially ordered set $P$ has the property that every chain (i.e. totally ordered subset) has an upper bound in $P$. Then the set $P$ contains at least one maximal element.

The set of even numbers is a totally ordered subset, therefore not every chain has an upperbound in $P$. Is this true? I suppose by maximal element we mean that $(\exists m\in S)(\forall x \in S) : x \preceq m$.

Comment: Even more simply, $\Bbb N$ is a chain in $\Bbb N$ with no upper bound. However, what you’ve defined at the end is a *maximum* element of $S$: everything else is smaller. A *maximal* element is one that is not smaller than anything else, though it may be incomparable with some elements. The partial order of proper subsets of $\{0,1,2\}$ has no maximum element, but $\{0,1\}$, $\{0,2\}$, and $\{1,2\}$ are all maximal elements.

Comment: Ah, thanks. So it doesn't hold for $\mathbb{R}$, but it does for $\mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty, -\infty\}$.

Comment: Yes, that’s correct.

Comment: Just a slight wording correction, but it's worth being careful about this:  Zorn's lemma certainly holds for ${\mathbb N}$, because it holds for any partially ordered set.  It is the *hypothesis* and the *conclusion* of Zorn's Lemma that don't hold for ${\mathbb N}$.

Comment: @WillO I suppose you'd say it doesn't _apply_, not that it doesn't _hold_.